# OFL Fonts - Allowed to embed in Word template?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, embedded, legal, embedded-fonts

I'm working on a Word template for a client who has this custom font in Open Font License. I've never done any work previously with fonts like this, and I read that it's meant to be open source and free. As long as it's not sold in any bundled way.

Now, in this case it's a Word template that is indeed sold to a client. But the font isn't really sold percè, it's just embedded in the template.

Would this be appropriate to do? I wouldn't want to get myself or my client into any legal issues because of something as mundane as a font.

Comment: Ship the template without an embedded font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much restriction on OFL-licensed fonts usage in documents.
See [this question in the OFL-FAQ](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL-FAQ_web&_sc=1#5b68ca67):

> Question: 1.13 Does embedding alter the license of the document itself?
>
> Answer: No. Referencing or embedding an OFL font in any document does not change the license of the document itself. The requirement for fonts to remain under the OFL does not apply to any document created using the fonts and their derivatives. Similarly, creating any kind of graphic using a font under OFL does not make the resulting artwork subject to the OFL

And [this question](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL-FAQ_web&_sc=1#c26665c2):

> Question: 1.1 Can I use the fonts for a book or other print publication, to create logos or other graphics or even to manufacture objects based on their outlines?
>
> Answer: Yes. You are very welcome to do so. Authors of fonts released under the OFL allow you to use their font software as such for any kind of design work. No additional license or permission is required, unlike with some other licenses. Some examples of these uses are: logos, posters, business cards, stationery, video titling, signage, t-shirts, personalised fabric, 3D-printed/laser-cut shapes, sculptures, rubber stamps, cookie cutters and lead type.

Beyond usage in documents, and if the font is modified, see also [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/879/947) on the Open-Source Stack Exchange.

See also several related fonts-license questions in the Open-Source Stack Exchange such as:

- [When does a forked project require a license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/863/when-does-a-forked-project-require-a-license)
- [How to properly include a license file within an EPUB?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/how-to-properly-include-a-license-file-within-an-epub)
- [GPL-FE (font-exception) on Apple App Store?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/gpl-fe-font-exception-on-apple-app-store)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you for the editing. Nice job :)